# Linear system of divisors as a projective space

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, dual-spaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$, let $\Sigma$ be the linear system of a very ample divisor $D$ on $S$, and let $d$ be the dimension of $\Sigma$.

I know that  if $\mathcal{L}$ is the line bundle associated to $D$, the set  $\Sigma$ is in a natural bijection with $(\Gamma(S,\mathcal{L})\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{C}^*$ and is therefore a projective space. Some time ago, I read in a paper that  we can identify $\Sigma$ with $\mathbb{P}^{d*}$, where
$\mathbb{P}^{d*}$ is the dual projective space of  $\mathbb{P}^{d}$.

I am just learning about linear systems, and is not clear for me how the identification $\Sigma=\mathbb{P}^{d*}$ goes. I will be grateful if someone can illuminate me.

Comment: Sorry for the deleted comment, I think I misunderstood your question. Which identification is confusing? Is it $\Sigma \sim \Gamma(S, \mathcal{L}) \setminus \{0\}/\mathbb{C}^*$ or is it $\Gamma(S, \mathcal{L}) \setminus \{0\}/\mathbb{C}^* \sim \mathbb{P}^d$? Check out Hartshorne II.7.7 and II.5.19 for some details.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for you comment and suggestions. I just edited my question to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: You say you know it's a projective space - this means it's $\Bbb P^m$ for some $m$. Is that the problem? Or is something else the issue? It's hard for me to tell exactly what doesn't connect for you.

Comment: Dear @KReiser I would like to know how we can identify $\Sigma$ with $\mathbb{P}^{d*}$.

Comment: You're just repeating yourself without clarifying anything. Until you explain a bit more about what specifically is the problem I don't think you're going to get much help.

Comment: Dear @KReiser thank you for your comment. Well, I do not understand why the identification is with the dual $\mathbb{P}^{d*}$ and not just with $\mathbb{P}^{d}$.

Comment: Ah! I can help here. The identification sends a point of $S$ not to a one-dimensional subspace of $\Gamma = \Gamma(S,\mathcal L) \cong \mathbb C^{d+1}$, but to a codimension one subspace; namely, for general $x \in S$ the subspace of $\Gamma$ which vanishes at $x$ is a hyperplane in $\Gamma$. Hence the identification is not with the ordinary projectivization of $\Gamma$ but its dual.

Comment: I realised that I did not clarify that $\mathbb{P}^{d*}$ is  the dual projective space of $\mathbb{P}^{d}$, sorry for that! Dear @Tabes Bridges thank you for your explanation!